# If condition not returning desired result in json array

Tags: php

I want to push 'Ab' in array when attremark is null. I used the below code to push 'Ab' in array.but it does not push it in array. What is wrong in my if condition?

```
$q1 = "select to_char(tin, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mm:ss') as tin, 
  to_char(tout, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mm:ss') as tout from npinout 
  where compcode='".$compcode."' 
  and empcode='".$empcode."' 
  and to_char(tin, 'MON-YYYY') ='".$date."' 
  and trunc(tin)='".$stmtb['DT']."' 
  ORDER BY tin " ;
            
            $rs1=oci_parse($con,$q1);
            $ex1=oci_execute($rs1); 
        
            while($row1= oci_fetch_assoc($rs1))
            {
                    if($stmtb['ATTREMARK']=='')
                    {
                        $stmtc['TIN']="Ab";
                        $stmtc['TOUT']="Ab";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     
                        $stmtc['TIN']=$row1['TIN'];
                        $stmtc['TOUT']=$row1['TOUT'];
                    } 
                    echo json_encode($stmtc); 
            }
```

How to push 'Ab' in array when attremark is null in php?

Comment: Where have you defined `$stmtb['ATTREMARK']`?

Comment: you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php?

Comment: I cannot really tell from what you have in the example, but are you sure your `cases` are the same?

Comment: Why are you outputing your JSON in the middle of the loop - the output will not be parseable as JSON. Why do you think the code you have shown us is not working as you expect? Did you check the value of `$stmtb['ATTREMARK']`?

Comment: Because if array is null we want to output result, that's all

Comment: There are some potential SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Comparisons are strange. Best thing to do is a `var_dump` on that value. so you can see what it really is. My guess would be it is simply null.

```
if (is_null($stmtb['ATTERMARK'])
```

I think your issue is you're looking for an empty string `''` which is not actually null. Another thing to look out for is your conditionals `==` != `===`. A better solution would be `($stmtb['ATTERMARK'] === null)` IF you want to check that it is null.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to check the empty value of a key.

```
 //checking for both null and empty

 if(empty($stmtb['ATTREMARK']) || is_null($stmtb['ATTREMARK'])){
       // do your stuff here
    }
```

If you want to check only null or empty use the single check.